# Enumerate numpy array differently?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

arr= np.arange(date(2020, 1, 1), date(2021, 1, 1)).astype(str)
dict_required = dict(enumerate(arr))
```

above is the stuff, I am doing. This is the dictionary I get:

```
{0: '2020-01-01',
 1: '2020-01-02',
 2: '2020-01-03',
 3: '2020-01-04',
```

I want it other way. The key above should be value and value should be key. I am able to invert it like below. But, is it possible to do the same while enumerating?

```
inv_map = {v: k for k, v in dict_required.items()}
```

Comment: `{d: i for i, d in enumerate(arr)}`

Comment: You were iterating over the dictionary items, I am enumerating the array

Comment: You were doing the equivalent of  `{i: d for i, d in enumerate(arr)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add another solution to the one given in comments (`{v:k for k,v in enumerate(arr)`, which is the most "pythonesque", and has the advantage, in your case to avoid builing the 1st dictionary)

You can reverse a dictionary that way:

```py
dict(map(reversed, mydic.items()))
```

Comment: Hi @chrslg might be bymistake you have add wrong code ``{v:k for k,d in ***`` ?

Comment: @R.Baraiya Indeed. Corrected. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try following way, where we creating new dictionary by putting old dict values on keys positions and keys to values positions.

Code:

```
dict(zip(dict_required.values(), dict_required.keys()))
```

Or

```
dict(zip(dict_required.values(),dict_required))
```